Adjoint transformation in abstract settings

Adjoint transformation in an abstract setting. The above main identity $(A\mathbf x, \mathbf y) = (\mathbf x, A^* \mathbf y)$ can be used to define the adjoint operator in abstract setting, where $A: V \to W$ is an operator acting from one inner product space to another. Namely, we define $A^* : W \to V$ to be the operator $A^*$ by defining its matrix $[A^*]_{\mathcal {AB}}$ as
$$
[A^*]_{\mathcal {AB}} = ([A]_{\mathcal{BA}})^*. (1)
$$
Consider orthonormal bases $\mathcal{A} = v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$ in $V$, $\mathcal{B} = w_1, w_2, ..., w_n$ in $W$.
We leave the proof that this indeed gives the adjoint operator as an exercise for the reader.

(link to screenshot from linear algebra done wrong, p 143)
Before this page, the book proves the main property of the adjoint matrix: $(A\mathbf x, \mathbf y) = (\mathbf x, A^* \mathbf y)$, for all $x$ and $y$. Now it says this property is used to define the adjoint of an operator when it comes to abstract operators.
The book gives an abstract operator $A$, acting from inner product space $V$ to inner product space $W$, both of whom use the Hermitian inner product.
Now, to find the adjoint operator of $A$, the book says, we define another operator $A^*: W \to V$, which satisfies the main property, i.e., $(Ax, y)=(x, A^*y)$ for all $x$ and $y$.
Here comes to proving the existence of such an operator $A^*$. The book says, consider orthonormal bases $\mathcal{A} = v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$ in $V$, $\mathcal{B} = w_1, w_2, ..., w_n$ in $W$. If $[A]_{\mathcal{BA}}$ is the matrix of A with respect to these bases, the matrix of $A^*$ should be $[A^*]_{\mathcal {AB}} = ([A]_{\mathcal{BA}})^*$.
I am confused about this. If written in matrix entries, $([A]_{\mathcal{BA}})^*$ has row vectors $\overline{[Av_i]}_{\mathcal{B}}$ while $[A^*]_{\mathcal{A} \mathcal{B}}$ has column vectors $[\overline{A^T} w_i]_{\mathcal{A}}$.
Take $M$ to be a unitary $n$ by $n$ matrix such that $Mv_i = w_i \forall i=1, 2, ..., n$. Then we get LHS of (1) = $[A^*]_{\mathcal {AB}}=[A^\dagger M]_{\mathcal{AA}}$, RHS of (1) = $([A]_{\mathcal{BA}})^*=([AM^\dagger]_{\mathcal{BB}})^T$. They are not the same. Why? Are they the same but I fail to see it, or is there a mistake in my calculations?

Please do not rely on pictures of text.

@Shaun I can type them out of course, but why not pictures? Is that a MSE community guideline or cultural convention thing? I mean if it’s offensive or inappropriate the website would have removed the functionality already. And thank you in advance for clarification.

They're not user friendly.  There are guidelines.  (I'm a little busy right now, so hopefully someone could find them in the meantime.)  They can't be searched.  Screen readers for the visually impaired cannot parse them.

@2512490741 You'll need to explain the notation a bit: I suspect that $\mathcal A, \mathcal B$ are bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively, with $\mathcal A = {v_1,\dots,v_n}$ and $\mathcal B = {w_1,\dots,w_m}$. Is all of that correct? Either way, it would be helpful if you could edit your question to address this point

@2512490741 Also, it would help if you could clarify your question: are you expecting the rows of $([A]{\mathcal {BA}})^$ to match up with the columns of $[A^]{\mathcal {AB}}$? Shouldn't it be the columns of the first that match with the columns of the second, since these two matrices are supposed to be equal? I'm not sure if this is your fundamental confusion that motivated the question or a trivial mistake that has gotten in the way of what you're trying to ask.

@BenGrossmann Thank you for pointing out, just edited

@BenGrossmann for the given rows of RHS and columns of LHS, they do not match, that is where I'm confused

@2512490741 We are trying to show that matrices P and Q are equal. You are apparently confused by the fact that the columns of Q don’t match the rows of P, but this seems strange. Instead, for P and Q to be equal, the columns of Q should match the columns of P. Why are you comparing rows to columns?

@BenGrossmann Thank you but I am not confused about that trivial point you mentioned. My approach is this: since $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are both orthonormal basis, there exists a unitary matrix $M$, such that $Mv_i = w_i \forall i$.

@BenGrossmann then RHS = $[AM^\dagger]{\mathcal{BB}}^T$, while LHS = $[A^\dagger M]{\mathcal{AA}}$. They are not the same.

btw can other people see my subscripts denoting the bases? I can see them on cellphone and iPad sites, but they show up as empty squares on my laptop.

I can see the subscripts. Maybe you could spell out to which equation LHS and RHS refer. It's not obvious to me what you're argument is that they should be equal.

@2512490741 Yes, the subscripts are there. The question still stands: why are you comparing the columns of the LHS to the rows of the RHS instead of comparing columns to columns (or rows to rows)?

@BenGrossmann I'm not comparing rows to columns or columns to rows. I picked out rows/columns of the two matrices to analyze. My confusion is that the two matrices are not the same according to my calculations.

@2512490741 I understand your point now. Well, in short, your calculation is incorrect. For one thing, $M$ would be an operator, not a matrix (otherwise, it's not clear what $Mv_i$ means for a vector $v_i \in V$, since $V$ is only stated to be an inner product space), and you never say what $A^\dagger$ is supposed to be. For the other, if $[A^*]{\mathcal {AB}} = [A^\dagger M]{\mathcal{AA}})$ and $\dagger$ is meant to be some version of the adjoint, then it would follow that $[A]{\mathcal{AB}} = [M^\dagger A]{\mathcal {AA}}$.

Perhaps this proof of the result will resolve your confusion.
A convenient aspect of working with orthonormal bases is that inner products can be computed as
$$
(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) = {[\mathbf y]_{\mathcal A}}^*[\mathbf x]_{\mathcal A}.
$$
Moreover, the $j,k$ entry of an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ can be computed as $\mathbf e_j^* M\mathbf e_k$, where $\mathbf e_1, \dots, \mathbf e_n$ denotes the standard basis of $\Bbb C^n$. With that in mind, we have
\begin{align}
([A^*]_{\mathcal{AB}})_{j,k} &= \mathbf e_j^*[A^*]_{\mathcal{AB}} \,\mathbf e_k
\\ & = [\mathbf v_j]_{\mathcal A}^* [A^*]_{\mathcal{AB}} [\mathbf w_k]_{\mathcal B}
\\ & = [\mathbf v_j]_{\mathcal A}^* [A^* \mathbf w_k]_{\mathcal{A}}
\\ & = (A^* \mathbf w_k, \mathbf v_j)
\\ & = (\mathbf w_k, A\mathbf v_j)
\\ & = [A\mathbf v_j]_{\mathcal B}^* [\mathbf w_k]_{\mathcal B}
\\ & = ([A]_{\mathcal {AB}}[\mathbf v_j]_{\mathcal B})^*[\mathbf w_k]_{\mathcal B}
\\ & = [\mathbf v_j]_{\mathcal A}([A]_{\mathcal {AB}})^* [\mathbf w_k]_{\mathcal B}
\\ & = \mathbf e_j^* ([A]_{\mathcal{AB}})^* \mathbf e_k = {([A]_{\mathcal{AB}})^*}_{j,k}.
\end{align}
The two matrices have the same entries, so they are the same matrix.
